# How to get an image thumbnail from a Pinterest video?

Tags: api, url, iframe, thumbnails, pinterest

Is there a simple way to get the image thumbnail address from a Pinterest video like this?

> https://assets.pinterest.com/ext/embed.html?id=227431849917701427

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [py3-pinterest](https://github.com/bstoilov/py3-pinterest) unofficial pinterest api.

```
import json

pin_data = load_pin_by_id(pin_id='227431849917701427')

print(json.dumps(pin_data))
```

And here is the `pin_data` json

https://pastebin.com/415w5de2

In the json `videos` -> `V_720P`-> `thumbnail`

https://i.pinimg.com/videos/thumbnails/originals/31/a1/5e/31a15e837c7eae841051968184580632.0000001.jpg